# Timescale: view don't auto update new data

Tags: timescaledb

I create a view like that:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view_cdn WITH ( timescaledb.continuous, timescaledb.materialized_only = TRUE)
 AS SELECT
time_bucket ( '5m', event_time ) AS times,
pn_id,
    cdn_list,
    video_type,
    cdn_id,
    platform,
    sum(viewer) as viewer,
    sum(cdn) as cdn,
    sum(error) as error,
    sum(cancel) as cancel,
    sum(total) as total,
    sum(bitrate) as bitrate,
    sum(t2fb_time) as t2fb_time,
    sum(response_time) as response_time

FROM
    sumary_report

GROUP BY
    times,
    pn_id,
    cdn_list,
    video_type,
    cdn_id,
    platform;

SELECT
    add_continuous_aggregate_policy ( 'view_cdn', start_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour', end_offset => INTERVAL '5 minute', schedule_interval => INTERVAL '5 minute' );
```

but view don't update new data from raw table, any one can help me? thanks.

Comment: You can check from PostgreSQL log file if continuous aggregate policy is running - it will write a log line every time the policy is run.